# Certificate issues when accessing app deployed on WebSphere Liberty cluster

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, websphere-liberty

I have set up a Liberty cluster comprising of the following:
 **node 1**- 10.11.12.201 server1
 **node 2**- 10.11.12.202 - server2, controller server, IHS load balancer with HTTPS enabled.
 
Have enabled dynamic routing feature at the load balancer level following ibm docs. Deployed my app on the server and tried accessing it follows:https://10.11.12.202/app/console.

The Internal proxy request is failing with :

ERROR com.kony.mobilefabric.util.restclient.RestCallHelper - GET call to 'https://10.11.12.202:443/app/api/v1_0/accounts/config' failed with error: Host name '10.11.12.202' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (DC=com.ibm.ws.dynamic.routing, OU=dynamicrouting, CN=WebServer)
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Host name '10.11.12.202' does not match the certificate subject provided by the peer (DC=com.ibm.ws.dynamic.routing, OU=dynamicrouting, CN=WebServer)

I guess this issue will be solved by updating the CN from "WebServer" to 10.11.12.202? i checked all the possible options for the dynamicRouting command but havent been able to figure out how to do this. Note i do not have DNS hence using Ip addresses.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you repurpose plugin-key.kdb as your frontend KeyFile? It is not wise.

Comment: Had followed these instructions upon successful execution of the dynamicRouting command: Copy the WebSphere plug-in configuration file to the directory specified
in the WebSpherePluginConfig directive in the IBM HTTP Server httpd.conf
file. Copy keystore file plugin-key.p12 to a directory on the
web server host, and run "gskcmd" to convert the keystore to CMS format and
to set personal certificate as the default.

Comment: Maybe your KeyFile directive was already pointing to plugin-key.kdb instead of an explicitly created key file.

Comment: rechecked. Looks fine to me. Heres my config                                                                                       
 LoadModule ibm_ssl_module modules/mod_ibm_ssl.so
Listen 443
SSLCheckCertificateExpiration 30
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEnable
SSLProxyEngine ON

</VirtualHost>

SSLDisable

KeyFile /home/Liberty/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/webserver1/plugin-key.kdb

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the generated plugin-key.kdb as the key store supplied with the `KeyFile` directive. It is generated for outbound connectivity in the WAS plugin, not for incoming requests to IHS.

If you want a useable frontend certificate, create a new KDB file with $IHSROOT/bin/gskcapicmd, create a certifcate request in it with the correct subjectAltName extensions, and get it signed.  Point to it with the `KeyFile` directive.